# MoveIt!2 Multiple Controllers for the Same Joints

Tags: ros2, moveit, multi-robot, manipulation

Multi-arm question:
I have a setup with a few Panda arms, and I have created a move group (+controllers) for each of the arms as well as a `panda_multi_arm` which is the concatenation of all joints of the arms. This last move group is created to plan for all arms together as a single robot. In ROS Noetic, this was working fine. In ROS2 Humble though, planning for each single arm works fine, but when planning for the `panda_multi_arm` group, planning succeeds and the execution fails with:

```
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1704026640.292585526] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.execute_trajectory_action_capability]: Received goal request
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1704026640.292727312] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.execute_trajectory_action_capability]: Execution request received
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1704026640.292785214] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 9 controllers in list
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1704026640.292839223] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 9 controllers in list
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1704026640.293066150] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Validating trajectory with allowed_start_tolerance 0.01
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1704026640.292823233] [move_group_interface]: Execute request accepted
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1704026640.296733134] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Starting trajectory execution ...
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1704026640.296783025] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 9 controllers in list
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1704026640.296819188] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 9 controllers in list
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1704026640.296965077] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: sending continuation for the currently executed trajectory to panda_multi_arm_controller
[ros2_control_node-4] [INFO] [1704026640.297198470] [panda_multi_arm_controller]: Received new action goal
[ros2_control_node-4] [ERROR] [1704026640.297242179] [panda_multi_arm_controller]: Can't accept new action goals. Controller is not running.
[move_group-2] [ERROR] [1704026640.297505397] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Goal was rejected by server
[move_group-2] [ERROR] [1704026640.297517075] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Failed to send trajectory part 1 of 1 to controller panda_multi_arm_controller
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1704026640.297524774] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Completed trajectory execution with status ABORTED ...
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1704026640.297506790] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: panda_multi_arm_controller started execution
[move_group-2] [WARN] [1704026640.297555013] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Goal request rejected
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1704026640.297570268] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.execute_trajectory_action_capability]: Execution completed: ABORTED
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1704026640.297820616] [move_group_interface]: Execute request aborted
```

When looking at the available controllers, I noticed that the multi-arm controller was inactive:

```
$ ros2 control list_controllers

panda_multi_arm_controller[joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController] active    
panda_one_hand_controller[position_controllers/GripperActionController] active    
panda_one_arm_controller[joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController] inactive  
panda_zero_arm_controller[joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController] inactive  
panda_three_arm_controller[joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController] inactive  
panda_two_arm_controller[joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController] inactive  
panda_three_hand_controller[position_controllers/GripperActionController] active    
panda_zero_hand_controller[position_controllers/GripperActionController] active
```

Removing the single-robot controllers "fixes" this, and the trajectories are executed properly. I'd like to still have those single-agent controllers though :). Any advice?